# How to copy all attributes of one Python object to another?

Tags: python, class, oop, object, inheritance

I've got two classes, of which one inherits from the other:

```
class DaParent(object):
    name = ''
    number = 0

class DaChild(DaParent):
    additional = ''
```

I now create a Parent and change the attributes:

```
parent = DaParent()
parent.name = 'papa'
parent.number = 123
```

And from this point, I want to create a Child in which I want to copy all the attributes from the parent. I can of course do this like so:

```
child = DaChild()
child.name = parent.name
child.number = parent.number
```

The thing is that while developing, this class will grow to have a fairly large number of attributes, and I don't constantly want to change the manual copying of the attributes into the child.

Is there a way to automatically take over the attributes of the parent object into a new child object? All tips are welcome!

[EDIT]
Just to explain the WHY I want to do this. I use the [Peewee ORM](http://peewee.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) to interact with my DB. I now want to revision a table (meaning if a record gets updated, I want keep all previous versions). The way I intent to do that is by for example creating a `Person` class and a `PersonRevision` class which inherits from the `Person` class. I then override the [peewee save() method](https://github.com/coleifer/peewee/blob/master/peewee.py#L3546-L3565) to not only save the `Person` object, but also copy all attributes into a `PersonRevision` object and save that as well. Since I will never actually directly interact with the `PersonRevision` class I don't need shadowing or any fancy stuff. I just want to copy the attributes and call the object its `save()` method.

Comment: Do you actually want those to be *class*, rather than *instance* attributes?

Comment: @jonrsharpe - As far as I understand they need to be instance attributes, so attributes of the object, not the class itself.

Comment: That is **not** what you have now - attributes defined inside `class` but outside an instance method `def` are *class attributes*.

Comment: Trying to be sure I understand: Is child supposed to shadow parent? I.e. if parent.name changes, is child.name also supposed to change?

Comment: Based on the names, you definitely don't want to use inheritance. A child *has* a parent, but it *is* not (at least for a while) a parent.

Comment: @chepner: I thinks these names are metasyntactic variables ;)

Comment: @kramer65: ok, it's far more specific then. You want to retrieve the list of db fields names from the peewee model (I could tell you how to do so in Django but for peewee you'll have to check the doc or inspect your models in a Python shell or read the source code to find out how). Then if `peewee` stores fields values as instance attributes (the way Django do) it's just a matter of `getattr` / `setattr` (or even using direct instance `__dict__` access).

Comment: @kramer65: added a "possibly working" code example based on a very quick at `peewee` source code. And you should really read about "XY problem"... Not that your "solution" (your initial question) was way off the mark, but it was far too generic. Stating your real use case right from the start would have make things clearer and avoided a lot of noise. HTH.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The obvious solution is to use composition/delegation instead of inheritence:

```
class Parent(object):
   def __init__(self, name, number):
       self.name = name
       self.number = number


class Child(object):
    def __init__(self, parent, other):
        self.parent = parent
        self.other = other

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        try:
            return getattr(self.parent, name)
        except AttributeError, e:
            raise AttributeError("Child' object has no attribute '%s'" % name)

p = Parent("Foo", 42)
c = Child(p, "parrot")
print c.name, c.number, c.other
p.name = "Bar"
print c.name, c.number, c.other
```

This is of course assuming that you dont really want "copies" but "references to". If you really want a copy it's also possible but it can get tricky with mutable types:

```
import copy

class Parent(object):
   def __init__(self, name, number):
       self.name = name
       self.number = number


class Child(object):
    def __init__(self, parent, other):
        # only copy instance attributes from parents
        # and make a deepcopy to avoid unwanted side-effects
        for k, v in parent.__dict__.items():
            self.__dict__[k] = copy.deepcopy(v)
        self.other = other
```

If none of these solutions fit your needs, please explain your *real* use case - you may have an XY problem.

[edit] Bordering on a XY problem, indeed. The real question is: "How do I copy a `peewee.Model`'s fields into another `peewee.Model`. `peewee` uses descriptors (`peewee.FieldDescriptor`) to control access to model's fields, and store the fields names and definitions in the model's `_meta.fields` dict, so the simplest solution is to iterate on the source model's `_meta.fields` keys and use `getattr` / `setattr`:

```
class RevisionMixin(object):
    @classmethod
    def copy(cls, source, **kw):
        instance = cls(**kw)
        for name in source._meta.fields:
            value = getattr(source, name)
            setattr(instance, name, value)
        return instance

class Person(peewee.Model):
     # fields defintions here


class PersonRevision(Person, RevisionMixin):
    # additional fields definitions here


p = Person(name="foo", number=42)
r = PersonRevision.copy(p, whatelse="parrot")
```

NB : untested code, never used `peewee`, there's possibly something better to do...

Comment: Is there a good way of reusing the `__getattr__` method in different classes? I'm building some wrappers and would like to use multiple times without duplicating the code.

Comment: Also, for what it's worth, I modified the Exception to programmatically grab the class name of the instance: `"{0} object has no parameter {1}".format(type(self).__name__, name))`

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to have a single parent with multiple children, and the children should be updated to match the parent whenever the parent changes, then have the parent's attributes be class attributes instead, and the "copying" to children will be automatic.

If you are going to have multiple parents, and at least some parents will have children, there are three options:

- use delegation (have the child look in the parent for anything it doesn't know about
- use copying (what you are doing now)
- use metaclasses to create a new parent class for each different parent, then each parent have its attributes as class attributes.

Answer (score 0):

I think a good option would be to use the parent (attributes) dictionary (`parent.__dict__`) to fill the child (attributes) dictionary (`child.__dict__`). You will need a `@classmethod` to create a child from a particular parent. The next code sample shows how to do that in your example:

```
class DaParent(object):
    name = ''
    number = 0


class DaChild(DaParent):
    additional = ''

    @classmethod
    def from_parent(cls, parent):
        child = cls()

        for attribute_key in parent.__dict__.keys():
            child.__dict__[attribute_key] = parent.__dict__[attribute_key]

        return child


if __name__ == '__main__':
    parent = DaParent()
    parent.name = 'papa'
    parent.number = 123

    child = DaChild.from_parent(parent)

    print(child.name)
    print(child.number)
```

#### Further explanation:

##### @classmethod

A class method is a static method, *i.e.*: it should be called from the class itself (`DaChild.from_parent`) instead of from an instance of the class (`child.from_parent`).

It has the variable `cls` as first attribute (like the `self` of the `__init__`) that may be used as a constructor, like in the example, the part `child = cls()`

##### Filling the dictionary

The attributes of a python object can be accessed and modified through its dictionary (like in the part `child.__dict__[attribute_key] = parent.__dict__[attribute_key]`).

I looped through the keys for getting all the attributes of the parent. Notice that you can modify the loop to fill the attributes you want, filtering the undesired ones with an `if ... else ...` for example.